# How to evaluate angularjs expression inside another expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a  element that prints a message. That message contains dynamic values.
So, how can i evaluate what's inside the message before it gets evaluated inside the  tag?

`$scope.name = 'John'
$scope.message = 'Hello {{name}}'`

`<li>{{message}}<li>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$interpolate` service to evaluate that expression.

```
.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $interpolate) {
   $scope.name = 'John';
   $scope.message = $interpolate('Hello {{name}}')($scope);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**ryeballar** is right. or  you can do it like this:

```
$scope.name = 'John'
$scope.message = 'Hello'+ $scope.name;

<li>{{message}}<li>
```