# Angular JS - nesting templates (double curly brackets {{}} )

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to nest angular templates?

for example having the following variables:

```
$scope.myVar = 'hello {{name}}, you weigh {{weight}}'
$scope.name = '';
$scope.weight = '';
```

And having the html file looking something like:

```
<h1>{{myVar}}</h1>
<div>
    Your Name:
    <input ng-model="name" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    Your Weight:
    <input ng-model="weight" type="text">
</div>
```

And then have angular dynamically setting the name and weight template from myVar?

Comment: which routing library you are using?

Comment: You can't pass a string that has `{{}}` in it to the view without using `$compile` so angular knows about it. Why would you want to do it this way in the first place?

Comment: I have a template that I want to dynamically serve to users that they can edit. Long story short, I found this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588206/how-to-evaluate-angularjs-expression-inside-another-expression

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are looking for is meaningless. You could define a function like below and then call this function in the header.

```
$scope.myVar = function() {
    return 'hello ' + $scope.name + ' you weigh '+ $scope.weight;
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('mainController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = "test";
    $scope.weight = 100;
    $scope.myVar = function() { return 'hello ' + $scope.name + ' you weigh ' + $scope.weight; };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <h1>{{myVar()}}</h1>
        <div>
          Your Name:
          <input ng-model="name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
          Your Weight:
          <input ng-model="weight" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I thought the same exact thing when I saw the question. Then a little glance down and..BOOM!

Comment: @A.Sharma :) it happens sometimes. Thank you !

Comment: @Christos, I am trying to accomplish that because I am getting  a string of the form: 'hello {{name}}, you weigh {{weight}}' and would like to be able to display it on the view and have the name and weight dynamically appear.
Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @msmanek you could use something like https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js  to accomplish this, if you don't want to add any other variable

Comment: @Christos I saw your solution is working, but  I prefer to explicitly pass the arguments to function calls like this eg: `myVar(name, weight)`. How does your solution let Angular know that it has to evaluate `myVar()` when name or weight has changed?

Comment: @msmanek that's baked in. you would put 

Hello {{name}} you weigh {{weight}}. 

between the heading tags.

Comment: but that was not working because of scoping issues. So, I used the $interpolate service to bind it to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing that I had scoping errors. So, to solve the binding errors, I used $interpolate. See: [How to evaluate angularjs expression inside another expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588206/how-to-evaluate-angularjs-expression-inside-another-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you would just do:

```
<h1>Hello {{name}} you weigh {{weight}}</h1>
<div>
    Your Name:
    <input ng-model="name" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    Your Weight:
    <input ng-model="weight" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue because the whole point is to have the content of the <h1> tag being dynamically served.

Comment: The example you gave lends itself to be data bound (should have used double colons preceeding the vars too) so as to preserve a nice to read view/controller separation.  If the other text truly needs to be dynamic (not shown in your question), then sure use a controller function, or you could bind additional vars e.g. if the 'Hello' could be a 'Goodbye' potentially then I'd be inclined to use another var i.e. <h1>{{::greeting}} {{::name}} you weigh {{::weight}}.  Many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: I found this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588206/how-to-evaluate-angularjs-expression-inside-another-expression